# i try to query data where like and where

Tags: mysql, sql

this error
2 errors were found during analysis.

This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "WHERE" at position 64)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "WHERE" at position 64)
SQL query: Documentation

```
SELECT * FROM helpdeskrequest 
WHERE detail LIKE '%New PC%' 
AND WHERE type='HW'
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE type='HW'' at line 2
>   {SELECT * FROM helpdeskrequest
>   WHERE detail LIKE '%New PC%' AND WHERE type='HW'}

Comment: 2 Where's ... There can be only ONE @jeroen :) :)

Comment: The correct syntax is `where X and Y`, not `where X and where Y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the double `WHERE`:

```
SELECT * FROM helpdeskrequest
WHERE detail LIKE '%New PC%' AND  type='HW'
```